# Undefined index while trying to delete

Tags: php, indexing

I have a list of items displaying from my DB and when I try to use a function delete, I get the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\delete.php on line 3
```

My code;
Delete.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$delete = "DELETE FROM `cart` WHERE id='$id'";
mysql_query( $delete);
}         
?>
```

Index of the list part;

```
<div class="container">

    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection Failed");
    mysql_select_db("cart")or die("Connection Failed2");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products" or die("Connection Failed2");
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("error");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $id1=$row['id'];
    $name=$row['product_name'];
    ?>
    <div class="show">
    <span class="name"><?php echo $name;  ?></span>
    <span class="action"><a href="delete.php" id="<?php echo $id1; ?>" class="delete" title="Delete">Delete</a></span>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?> 
    </div>
```

Comment: use $_GET['id']; in delete.php

Comment: you should really consider using `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*` as mysql functions are deprecated and open to attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $id1; ?>" class="delete" title="Delete">Delete</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="delete.php" id="<?php echo $id1; ?>" class="delete" title="Delete">Delete</a>
```

And

```
if($_GET['id'])
```

instead of

```
if($_POST['id'])
```

Full Code

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if($_GET['id'])
{
$id=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$delete = "DELETE FROM `cart` WHERE id='$id'";
mysql_query( $delete);
}         
?>
```

And

```
<div class="container">

    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection Failed");
    mysql_select_db("cart")or die("Connection Failed2");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products" or die("Connection Failed2");
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("error");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $id1=$row['id'];
    $name=$row['product_name'];
    ?>
    <div class="show">
    <span class="name"><?php echo $name;  ?></span>
    <span class="action"><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $id1; ?>" class="delete" title="Delete">Delete</a></span>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?> 
    </div>
```

Comment: And check for $_GET instead of $_POST

Comment: Changed, and changed GET in the delete.php, but getting the same error

Comment: @VadimasDružinin $id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']); you changed that line too?

Comment: Okay, it worked now but i got a blank page after deleting on localhost, on wamp i got SRV Server:

Document Contains no data.  Is it a problem on my dabase connection?

Comment: @VadimasDružinin you have to redirect in a page after delete